# Firebird Guardian

Tags: firebird

Is there an opinion on running Firebird Guardian.  According to the FAQ - [The Firebird FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq31/):

> On Windows, having guardian running can even be counter-productive as
>   it would run fbserver.exe instead of fb_inet_server.exe, which can
>   create problems. Make sure you are not running guardian with classic
>   server

The reason I ask is we have started (just today or so), Firebird has been crashing a lot and I'm wondering if this is contributing - although we've never had any problems in the past.

And when I say crashing, looking at firebird.log, there's plenty of:

> "C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbserver.exe": terminated abnormally (4294967295)

and

> Fatal exception during clumplet dump: Invalid clumplet buffer
>   structure: spb in service attach should begin with isc_spb_version1 or
>   isc_spb_version

It's happened about 40 times today alone.

Is the guardian possible contributing, or does this point to another issue - if at all possible to even answer.  I can see the Guardian restarting fbserver.exe after these errors.

Also getting a few:

> DED430 (Server)   Mon May 11 13:57:39 2015
>        INET/inet_error: read errno = 10054

I'm thinking it might be network issue as it's being flogged.

Any insight would be helpful.  My first post here, so close or mark down if not appropriate or question makes no sense.

Running version 2.5.2

Comment: I just wonder why you're using Classic - it's more a Unix thing AFAIK. Secondly, you should always keep the guardian running. Finally, I think that you may have some corruption - I'd reinstall and choose the SuperServer option. Make sure you backup first.

Comment: Using the guardian is totally unnecessary: the Windows Service mechanism will perform the restart itself, so there is no need for the guardian.

Comment: Thanks.  I will investigate superserver.  We have 50+ databases connected through this server, so maybe superserver is more suited to that environment.  I'll also stop the Guardian service and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Jason If you disable the Guardian, then there is also a setting in firebird.conf that needs to change. Note that the actual problem might be a bug; I'd suggest you update to Firebird 2.5.4 (and if you are currently running Classic, then you shouldn't use Guardian at all)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yep.  Was looking at upgrading to the latest version.  Will research the firebird.conf and disabling of Guardian.  It has settled down for the moment, but feel I still need to do something.